# npm does not support Node.js v16.14.0

Tags: node.js, npm

I have seen several questions on this theme, usually with incompatible pairings of node/npm. In my case, I installed `node16` via `nvm` (which also gave me the appropriate `npm` with it), and mostly everything works well. Except, when I use `npm` to start my service, I get this message (though, other than the message, it works fine)

```
➜  zenodeo3 git:(master) which node
/Users/punkish/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node
➜  zenodeo3 git:(master) node -v
v16.14.0
➜  zenodeo3 git:(master) which npm
/Users/punkish/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/npm
➜  zenodeo3 git:(master) npm -v
8.3.1
➜  zenodeo3 git:(master) npm run dev

> zenodeo-fastify@3.0.0 dev
> npm run development

npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v16.14.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
```

weird, no?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem the solution for me was
Go to the path where you can find the debug log (this file is found in your npm-cache folder) if you are on windows you can find it when you press the windows button with the letter r and you put in "%AppData%/npm-cache"
Delete the NPM and NPM-Cache folder, but DO NOT reinstall node. Once deleted go back to your command line and re-use the command " npm install -g npm@latest "